# Can't figure out why hard drive is full

Tags: linux, debian, hard-drive, disk-space-utilization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How do I find out what is using up all the space on my / partition?](https://serverfault.com/questions/62119/how-do-i-find-out-what-is-using-up-all-the-space-on-my-partition)
>
> [No Free disk space](https://serverfault.com/questions/132998/no-free-disk-space)

so I have 2 hard drives in my server, one main one that is 10gb and then a separate one that is 2tb

I'm storing all the files on the second one and the df -h output looks like this

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2             9.2G  8.8G     0 100% /
tmpfs                 1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                  1.5G  148K  1.5G   1% /dev
tmpfs                 1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda4             1.8T  747G  981G  44% /home
/dev/sda4             1.8T  747G  981G  44% /usr/lib/cgi-bin
```

I just can't figure out why the first one is full when all the files are being stored in the /usr/lib/cgi-bin

I'm running debian

I can't seem to find any files that would take up 8.8gb that arn't on the second hard drive :S

Thanks!

Comment: You have `/dev/sda4` mounted twice. That's not good.

Comment: In addition to the 2 linked questions check out the Linked and Related questions in their sidebars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `du` command to track down where the space is being used up:

```
$ cd /
$ du -sm *
```

This can take some time to run, but when complete, it'll list the sizes of all the subdirectories of `/`. Once you find the largest subdir, say `/var` for instance, then change directory into `/var` and run the `du` command again.