# What does 'Can't sync file './database_name/…frm' to disk (Errcode: 28)' mean?

Tags: mysql

I am getting this error message whenever I try to create a new index or a new table in my mysql server. Does anyone know what the reason is?
This is the ouput after I run df -a

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2              13G  7.3G  4.5G  63% /
/dev/sda1             251M   27M  212M  12% /boot
tmpfs                 3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
10.156.248.29:/vol/pharos_pnxd_data_01/env_empty_sbid_27133_qdcprod
                       30G   30G   32K 100% /app
```

Answer (score 6):

It probably means that the device is out of space:

```
# perror 28
OS error code  28:  No space left on device
```

Answer (score 0):

usually the disk is full. Are you on linux or windows?

on linux see which disk is full;

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                                           50G   18G   33G  35% /
devtmpfs                                        3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /dev
...
```

check the error code;

```
$ perror 28
OS error code  28:  No space left on device
```

you can look for big log files in  `/var/log`  with find;

```
# find /var/log -type f -size +50M -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{ print $9 ": " $5 }'
 /var/log/syslog: 352M
```

or look in `/var/` if thats the one thats full

```
 find /var/ -type f -size +50M -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{ print $9 ": " $5 }'
```

Comment: How do I see which files are taking too much space?

Comment: @cool_cs: start here follow the links http://serverfault.com/questions/394974/cant-figure-out-why-hard-drive-is-full and please don't cross post questions to multiple stackexchange sites.

Comment: Is it safe to remove the mysql log files?

Comment: I can only really point you at some posts on the matter- http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/12/09/be-careful-rotating-mysql-logs/

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/log-file-maintenance.html