# I can't find the ghosts taking up space on my hard drive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, df, du

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find out what is using up all the space on my / partition?](https://serverfault.com/questions/62119/how-do-i-find-out-what-is-using-up-all-the-space-on-my-partition)
>
> [No Free disk space](https://serverfault.com/questions/132998/no-free-disk-space)

```
$df -h
```

returns

```
/dev/sda1              16G   16G     0 100% /
tmpfs                 502M     0  502M   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                  497M  116K  497M   1% /dev
tmpfs                 502M     0  502M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sdb1             2.0T  886G  1.1T  47% /srv/ftp
/dev/sdc1              16G   12G  3.9G  75% /var/opt/CrushFTP6_PC/TempAccounts
```

then

```
$du -hs * | sort -rh
```

returns

```
886G    srv
12G     var
838M    usr
119M    lib
15M     boot
5.8M    bin
5.6M    etc
4.6M    sbin
2.4M    lib32
120K    root
116K    dev
```

The 886GB is on /dev/sdb1

the 12GB is on /dev/sdc1

Please help me figure out where the space is going on /dev/sda1. Are there files that I deleted that are still in use? If so how can I find them?

Comment: SDA1 contains /, and possibly log files in directories. Did you delete any log files (without restarting the program creating them).?

Comment: `df` uses the kernel's in-core idea of what's in use on the disk.  `du` walks the filesystem to see what's actually connected.  The only time the two are guaranteed to agree is when the filesystem is clean and newly mounted...

Answer (score 3):

Its likely you have an open file handle to a file you deleted. [See here](http://dag.wieers.com/blog/undeleting-an-open-file-by-inode) for how to use [lsof](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof) to find the file and the proc file system to close the handle.