# Errno::ENOSPC: No space left on device in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, ruby-on-rails-3

Iam hosting a Ruby on Rails Application on a Linode with 96 GB storage. All the images of my application are stored on amazon and they are fetched from amazon. Thus my linode should have a minimum of 80 GB storage free.

But when the **log files** of the application exceed 200 Mb I get the error:

```
Errno::ENOSPC: No space left on device
```

and my website goes down.

I enabled log rotation for my application on daily basis with the following code in file **/etc/logrotate.conf**:

```
path/to/application/log/*.log {
  daily
  missingok
  rotate 1
  compress
  delaycompress
  notifempty
  copytruncate
}
```

But now I have started getting the same error twics a day so I changed my config settings on the basis of size as:

```
path/to/application/log/*.log {
  size 1M
  missingok
  rotate 1
  compress
  delaycompress
  notifempty
  copytruncate
}
```

I also moved the logrotate file from /etc/cron.daily to /etc/cron.hourly so that the logrotate cronjob runs each hour and rotate the log if it exceeds 1M. I restarted the apache.

But when I checked after an hour my files sizes were greater than 1M. Thus the **logrotate cronjob didnt work after every hour**. When I forcefully rotate the log using the command:

```
 sudo /usr/sbin/logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.conf
```

then the log files gets rotated and the files size decrease.

I am not able to figure out why this configuration doesnt work. **Moreover when the space on linode is 80 GB how does it affect if log files exceeds 200 Mb**. What is the way to allocate more space to log directory?

As suggested I ran `df -ih` to check if Iam running out of **inodes**. The follwoing output I get:

```
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/xvda               2.2M    263K    2.0M   12% /
devtmpfs                174K    2.0K    172K    2% /dev
none                    174K       1    174K    1% /dev/shm
none                    174K      33    174K    1% /var/run
none                    174K       2    174K    1% /var/lock
none                    174K       1    174K    1% /lib/init/rw
```

Thus my inodes are almost free. Iam not running out of inodes.

The output of `df -h` is as:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda             9.5G  8.7G  325M  97% /
devtmpfs             1010M  112K 1010M   1% /dev
none                 1010M     0 1010M   0% /dev/shm
none                 1010M   52K 1010M   1% /var/run
none                 1010M     0 1010M   0% /var/lock
none                 1010M     0 1010M   0% /lib/init/rw
```

My disk space is really less. How should I proceed?

Please help.Many Thanks!

Comment: You may be running out of inodes. Check `df -h` and `df -hi`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I ran the command as you suggested and added the output in question. Please check and suggest.

Comment: Well, you're not running out of inodes.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz What can be the issue then?

Comment: So what is the output from `df -h`?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Output of df -h is added in the question. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true, you have very little space left.

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda             9.5G  8.7G  325M  97% /
```

Only a few hundred megabytes, and your disk will be full again.

You said you expected to have much more disk space than this shows, so I would recommend you contact Linode to find out what's going on.

Comment: Yeah. I just checked out. My older release have taken all the space on disk. I have deleted them and got the issue fixed. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

I had a the same error message when trying to run an `npm install`.

`npm ERR! nospc ENOSPC: no space left on device, open /{dir}/...`

The fix for me was the following:

- `sudo rm -rf node_modules` - Remove node_modules
- `df -hi` - Check the available disk space
- `sudo apt-get update` - Update packages
- `sudo apt-get autoremove` - Use 'autoremove' to remove packages that are no longer needed
- `sudo apt-get -f install` - Correct broken dependencies

Answer (score 2):

my 2 cents here:

I found out that the output of `lsof | grep -i deleted` was having production.log from several ages ago. Which a restart of the service freed up all the space. I got the idea from: [Disk full, du tells different. How to further investigate?](https://serverfault.com/questions/275206/disk-full-du-tells-different-how-to-further-investigate)

Comment: The link solved my problem: [Disk full, du tells different. How to further investigate?](https://serverfault.com/a/284269/364130)

Answer (score 0):

te eue  ebeebehujbs s hd dpqb d diqbduqbdhedq  qeqe qw eq euqwe qw je jqwiejqwelenfqlq oq8q dqwe 1 2e 12  w2 22 2 2  22j e 1 3jwuuqdqdhsidiphispidaspidhshdah'-9qjrgnerigiirjwnoir8gw kr gjrnkwegw;iienrnr rrids doeihwoeofne rogrojipfpirpirjrpwpwrpwerjpwrjpweroweoprjwepjopwejfindf d f  f f ffff s ffw fow    fdddd d d d d ddnqidnnonwifeowneroihweriowheriohewoirhwiehirhwoiehriower we r wer wer w er we r w er we r we r w er we r we r we rwer wer  weorinoiwninwoqoqnwowqriroriowewiironinonwoninefoifoiiofosififishfdihfohosfsoidfhshoiohfoihsoihfdoishdoifhoisdfosdf sfi f fjdjfofjj sifiosf ioosd fojsdfjfi ohsfjosfojsojfdiofdioifofdfflnsfioioofiwroiw0rhfiowhuibjnoij3rihdjfkrewfheuidbjkrojw8uihdfbjkerio8uegtbhrgnjeiruehgyuhjenriuhygjker4jhubjkrj4yeghjeritgkr423urfhdjgeriueghfjertugjikerijufhjwijufhghhgfdghjhgfghgfghgfghgygygfgfgytfgvgtfcfcfcfrfcfcfrcfrfcftfcftftffcftfvftfgtgvtfvftfvftvgtvgtgvtfvftft6fgyhff wwhe9rhwoerowheirhiowheoirowehorhowherhiowerhhweoriiewhroiwehorw0ur0wqeihroqohehohqpeiohiohoffhsifioahdoihof8qr8qw8rhwhqfh[whr880wrowfhdfh98wy98whf97uwqhuothqhrwheroiqhwoirhqw8iorhoiqhoriqhworih9q8hdodosufodsf8rqyrh08hohfoh07742394237423u4y2034y032974073274023942307947293709470923794792370983-58-85-88252034-283-42042-4233534-5-345-45-5-2-4--2-34234234234235325-2-52-5-----56-06-86-304880683-4863-6-38068083-6836-3853084-2-84-234-50834-0-34-54-5834583-05-3845-3045-03485-0-83-45834-503-50-3-0384583-580-3058-08435-0-385-385-385-0385-03-58-345-34503-4504-5-34-5034-34805-3405-3-4-93495204972440124797012974071042709707017147-0-43-40702474924-4-2470840248-48-14-1471-4-184-34824-4709273094174-14730273048177324702347234-4--4--2-4-2-974-2443---8--8-28--884288---948942342oijeioewrwe9ru-ewru0wer0ew-r*

BUTTER CUP! qogruwhjhqyihkqejpqujepiqhpieqp9uenlowfblu9fihnlapjdihjbflihuvbdkjvnflemwifudvhbjndkewljrifdhvu bdfkewrljpfivhdukbfwelmjudbvkhf ekwu9fdvihbjsfmlekjrifuvhdibkjfnrwemlfouvgibhk ewlkmfji huihbdkflmeivhuibdnf kn
BUTTER CUP!!!

### Heading ##10101000010101001101101001010101001010101011010100010010101010010101010001010100010100101001010100101101010101011101010101000100101010101001011001010101

*NUKE!!!!!!!!!!!NUKE!!!!!!!!!!!NUKE!!!!!!!!!!!!!NUKE!!!!!!!!!!!NUKE!!!!!!!!!