# MySQL accessing a lot of deleted temp files

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

MySQL version: mysql  Ver 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

I have a server that hosts a MySQL database and Apache Airflow.
It was working fine for a couple of months.
For a couple of days, my services are constantly crashing.

I see that the error is due to insufficient Disk Space:
These are the errors that I see when I try to run my Airflow Service.

[image]

[image]

This is happening even though I see there is disk space left:
[image]

I figured out that this could be due to a MySQL bug,
https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4267115/mysql-daemon-not-releasing-deleted-temp-file

But I have a newer version of MySQL installed so this should not happen.

Tried restarting the server a couple of times.

Tried killing the MySQL services manually, but it always goes back to the same state.

So I am not even able to get it fixed temporarily.

[image]

Not able to understand how to fix the error permanently, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disk full, du tells different. How to further investigate?](https://serverfault.com/questions/275206/disk-full-du-tells-different-how-to-further-investigate)

Comment: Lower `max_connections` in my.cnf to only 30.  Is `tmpdir` being set in the config file?

Comment: @MichaelHampton no I don't think that is realted.

Comment: @RickJames Lowered max connections, still the same.

Comment: Did you even look? What were the inode counts?

Comment: Yes, @MichaelHampton, Inodes were 100% used, I increased the disk space.
So seems it got solved temporarily.

Mysql is still accessing those deleted files.

So  I meant, MySQL accessing deleted temp files is unrelated.

Comment: I think you'll just have to restart MySQL.

Comment: I did that a couple of times, the PID changes, but it keeps accessing those files.

Comment: 100% inodes used -- sounds like lots of tiny files on the file system.  In my several decades of using *nix, I don't remember running out of inodes before running out of space.  I wouldn't even know what OS parameter to change to increase the ratio between inode and data blocks.

Comment: @RickJames 100% inodes were because of Airflow,
Each dag execution in Airflow creates a log directory(multiple jobs are running every couple of minutes), we have logrorate to delete the log files, but directories remain here.

I suppose that is what caused it.

Comment: I will write a cron to clean up empty directories and then try that.

Comment: @ofnowhere - Suggest filing a bug report with Airflow,

Comment: Not sure if it is a bad, but a bad implementation of a feature.

Answer (score 1):

Out of inodes?  Check with `df --inodes`

A quick, but temporary, fix would be to toss files in `.Trash` and `Download`

Maybe there are lots of unnecessary empty files:
https://www.interserver.net/tips/kb/solution-running-inodes/
https://askubuntu.com/questions/231585/running-out-of-inodes

Maybe "compressing" a few little-used disk trees would help.  (You will need a few free inodes before trying this.)  Or `tar` up some trees that you don't need.

(etc)