# Centos 7.4, dev/vda1 is 100%

Tags: centos, hard-drive, df, lsof, du

My VPS on DO now has an issue of dev/vda1 is 100% since around 3 months ago, at that time, I did poweroff & reboot then disk spaced freed.

But the thing rans into some bigger issue since 1 week ago, poweroff & reboot could not release free space any more. I tried thousands of researches but still failed to solve it, I was also sending ticket to DO but still ongoing.

My current enviroment:

0. my droplet is 25G , all swapfile & tmpfs are total of 2GB only
1. I deleted all unwanted files & all logs; my droplet is used to run sites only, no backup & storage; now all 7 sites take 2GB only
2. Others & database (include ibdata1 file) take around 2GB only
3. I deleted all unused core files, `lsof` command, etc.

`df -h` shows

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        25G   25G  444M  99% /
devtmpfs        476M     0  476M   0% /dev
tmpfs           497M     0  497M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           497M   26M  471M   6% /run
tmpfs           497M     0  497M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/0
```

`du -sh /` shows

```
du: cannot access ‘/proc/13568/task/13568/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/13568/task/13568/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/13568/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/13568/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
5.5G    /
```

Seems some issue ate 5.9GB at root path "/". So my real files, sites, progams & apps consumes 6GB only.

I also found [this topic was same](https://serverfault.com/questions/1091769/find-what-is-using-disk-space-in-centos-7-du-vs-df-vs-lsof) but seems this issue relates to XFS defragment then I said to DO supporter, they suggested me a file system check, then screenshot is result as you could see.

[image: a file system check]

Should I still perform XFS repair command to fix xfs defragment? How do I do?
Can you help me?
Many thanks

Comment: You still may try xfs_repair

Comment: thank you so much, **diya**; found `xfs_fsr` command to solve this issue, https://serverfault.com/questions/275206/disk-full-du-tells-different-how-to-further-investigate#comment1117943_848319