# Inconsistency between "du -sh" and "df -h"

Tags: du, df, disk-space-utilization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [du vs. df difference](https://serverfault.com/questions/57098/du-vs-df-difference)

I am running a server with Debian stable.

If I call:

```
df -h
```

this is the result I get:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/my-var   2.8G  2.3G  358M  87% /var
```

While if I call:

```
du -sh /var
```

This is the result I get:

```
832M    /var
```

How can this happen? Which one is correct? Thank you!

Comment: Hello, welcome to serverfault, this question has already been here : http://serverfault.com/questions/57098/du-vs-df-difference

Comment: lsof | grep deleted and check whether the deleted files are still holding space and then if required, restart the service

Answer (score 0):

One quite common reason, especially on `/var` is that some processes keep files open that are already deleted. The system will not actually free the space until they are closed, but they are not listed anymore and therefore not seen by `du`.

`/var` keeps log files among other things and this sort of issue can easily happen there.