# df report incorrect free space for a filesystem (ext4)

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, ext4, df

I am facing an issue with wrong fs space reported by `df`.

We are talking about bare metal Ubuntu 14.04 server, with the `/` partition managed by LVM.

Size reported by `df` is different from the size reported by fs super-block. Also calculating size from `du -skh` (on directories related to `/` partition) proves that `df` is showing incorrect results.

This is what reported by `df`:

```
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/rootvg-lv_root   20G   16G  2.8G  86% /
```

This is what super-block reports `(3616906*4096/1024**2=14128 MB free)`:

```
Last mounted on:          /
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem state:         clean
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              1290240
Block count:              5242880 << exactly 20 GB
Reserved block count:     227170
Free blocks:              3616906 << around 14 GB free
Free inodes:              1201391
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
```

I did a strace for `df` and found that it uses the `statfs` syscall to get information about a particular fs `(962132*4096/1024**2=3758 MB free)`:

```
statfs("/", {f_type="EXT2_SUPER_MAGIC", f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=5129119, f_bfree=**962132**, f_bavail=730866, f_files=1290240, f_ffree=1091851, f_fsid={-456623966, 1549023591}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0
```

Probably the problem with `statfs` or with a way how it fetches fs information.

To solve it I tried to remount `/` partition (`mount / -orw,remount`), but it didn't help.

My question - how can I fix `df` information without rebooting or disturbing normal operation of this server?

P.S.

- there are **no** fd on hold by process (`lsof +L1 | grep deleted`)
- I aware that 883 MB is reserved for user with UID 0
- This is not a mount point masking issue (when mounted fs 'hide' files in mount point directory)

Comment: What is the problem you want to fix?

Comment: Our monitoring is rely on `df` output. All I want - correct information to be reported by `df`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [du vs. df difference](http://serverfault.com/questions/57098/du-vs-df-difference)

Comment: Lain, thanks for pointing to masking (when you have files in directory which is used as mount point) issue, but this is not the case. It is seen by free blocks report in super-block (14 GB free), but `df` report only 2.8GB free. Probably the issue is more related to statfs and LVM.

Comment: @TomLime Where do you get that super-block info? I can't find a command called super-block... You using dumpe2fs or something?

Comment: @RyanBabchishin, yes exactly I ran command `dumpe2fs /dev/mapper/rootvg-lv_root`.

Comment: @TomLime I get 19,941MB from df and 82,860MB from the free blocks calculation on my system. Could your problem be due to sparse files? I don't really understand, it's just a stab in the dark. e.g. Is your filesystem actually storing 16G of data but not using all the blocks?

Comment: @RyanBabchishin, my system actually storing 6GB, but `df` wrongly reports 16GB. I tend to believe to SB information, as this is only the source of truth (how much blocks are free).

Comment: Check for unlinked (inode deleted, but file descriptor still in use) files: `lsof -a +L1 / | grep deleted`

Comment: @KarenB Unlinked files would cause du-vs-df inconsistency, but shouldn't cause `df` to be wrong.

Comment: @KarenB, I already did this check, nothing significant was found.

Comment: What does `du -skh --apparent-size /` would show? Can you allocate a 3gb file while only 2.8GB reported free by df on / with `fallocate -l 3GB /test.file` or will it say `fallocate failed: No space left on device`?

Comment: @Anubioz, `du -skh /` gave 8.4G, `du -skh --apparent-size /` gave 8.2G. 
I tried to allocate a file (3GB) and it gave me a message `fallocate failed: No space left on device`. I checked amount of free blocks with `dumpe2fs` and it had same value as before `fallocate`.

Answer (score 1):

in sake of fellows who stuck with same issue:

i solved it by issuing `unmount /dev/mapper/rootvg-lv_root`. it gave me an error, but after `df` reported correctly.

looks like `umount` refreshed some internal structs.

hope it help someone.

Comment: Helped to me, should be promoted to answer IMHO.